# What is the meaning of success & failure in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

In this init script you can see lines which say only `success` or `failure`.
What are these commands?

```
start)
echo -n "Starting Jenkins "
daemon --user "$JENKINS_USER" --pidfile "$JENKINS_PID_FILE" $JAVA_CMD $PARAMS > /dev/null
RETVAL=$?
if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]; then
    success
    echo > "$JENKINS_PID_FILE"  # just in case we fail to find it
    MY_SESSION_ID=`/bin/ps h -o sess -p $$`
    # get PID
    /bin/ps hww -u "$JENKINS_USER" -o sess,ppid,pid,cmd | \
    while read sess ppid pid cmd; do
        [ "$ppid" = 1 ] || continue
        # this test doesn't work because Jenkins sets a new Session ID
        # [ "$sess" = "$MY_SESSION_ID" ] || continue
        echo "$cmd" | grep $JENKINS_WAR > /dev/null
        [ $? = 0 ] || continue
        # found a PID
        echo $pid > "$JENKINS_PID_FILE"
    done
    touch $JENKINS_LOCKFILE
else
    failure
fi
echo
;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the answer. These are the functions defined in `/etc/init.d/functions`.

```
# Log that something succeeded
success() {
    [ "$BOOTUP" != "verbose" -a -z "${LSB:-}" ] && echo_success
    return 0
}

# Log that something failed
failure() {
    local rc=$?
    [ "$BOOTUP" != "verbose" -a -z "${LSB:-}" ] && echo_failure
    [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && /bin/plymouth --details
    return $rc
}
```